# Google Search for Android

Tags: android, search, google-search, android-searchmanager

I am trying to put a simple Google Search in my app. I found this code but it's not exactly what I am searching for. Below the search comes from a given url.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

The thing is that I would like to get the search text from user and if possible without starting a new Activity like this one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
String term = editTextInput.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text from the user and place that in the URI, then start the intent.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + userText;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```